# Uninterruptible Power Supply - Reset the load when power is restored

Tags: microcontroller, power, reset, ups, one-shot

My system is powered by a redundant supply (UPS).
When the input power supply is removed, the system detects this event and it performs a safe shutdown (actually it is a microcontroller that enters a power-down mode after performing few operations).

I would like a recommendation for an IC that resets the MCU when the input power is restored to restart the system.

I found some MCU supervisor circuits (like CAT825, TLV803) that reset the MCU at power-on, but they also keep the MCU under reset when the input voltage falls below a threshold, which is not desirable on my situation.

I know it can be done with a "one-shot" circuit built with a 555 IC, but I am looking for a small dedicated IC.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I also wonder how the majority of the "graceful shutdown" UPS products designed for Raspberry Pi works, after the power supply is restored the Pi needs to be manually restarted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used these in various similar situations, and perhaps one of the would suit your application:

- Edge-triggered interrupt pin on the MCU
- ATTiny25/45/85 as a reset controller feeding an interrupt or reset pin on the MCU (use Tiny's internal oscillator to keep part count down; use its power-on reset and brown-out detector to send whatever signal desired.)

Although an ATTiny seems like overkill, it's sometimes convenient: they are pretty small (6-pin, 8-pin) and $0.25/unit!

It's worth noting that many MCUs (including ATTiny) have **brown-out detectors**, which are specifically for this kind of application.

At least ATmega328 and ATTiny25 (and I'm sure many others) work like this:

> ATmega328P has an on-chip brown-out detection (BOD) circuit for monitoring the V<sub>CC</sub> level during operation by comparing it to a fixed trigger level. The trigger level for the BOD can be selected by the `BODLEVEL` fuses. The trigger level has a hysteresis to ensure spike free brown-out detection. The hysteresis on the detection level should be interpreted as V<sub>BOT+</sub> = V<sub>BOT</sub> + V<sub>HYST</sub>/2 and V<sub>BOT–</sub> = V<sub>BOT</sub> – V<sub>HYST</sub>/2.
>   ...
>   The BOD circuit will only detect a drop in V<sub>CC</sub> if the voltage stays below the trigger level for longer than t<sub>BOD</sub>

- V<sub>HYST</sub> is 50 mV (Tiny) 80 mV (Mega)
- V<sub>BOT</sub> is 2.7 ± 0.2 V or 4.3 ± 0.3 V, chosen in configuration fuses (also 1.8 V on ATTiny).
- t<sub>BOD</sub> is a few microseconds, 2μs on ATTiny.

[image]
(image and quote from Atmel datasheets)

Many other MPUs' brown-out detectors will have very similar properties, though of course the details will vary.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. After some time the battery voltage might drop to a level that can't guarantee the functionality of the MCU, so the interrupt might not work properly. I would also like to avoid an extra small MCU like ATTiny or PIC10F because it will introduce unwanted overhead in the production phase.

Comment: Hi @RolandKorg I'm not sure an ATTiny is any more overhead than the CAT825 you suggested, but certainly it's a part, with firmware, and that adds to complexity and that has a cost.  FWIW, I used an external 8-pin ATTiny25 to reset MPUs so that the "reliability code" (60 bytes hand assembler in the ATtiny) was nowhere near the working code (in the main MPU), and thus *nothing* the software designer did could affect the reset control.

Comment: Hi @jonathanjo. The Power MUX on my system (TPS2121) cuts the output voltage at 2.5V so the MCU will not operate outside the voltage limit (regarding my other question about the brown-out voltage). In this case your suggestion to use an interrupt pin is valid. Thank you.

Comment: I also found CAT871 and CAT872, Dual Input Reset Generator that can provide the "one-shot" reset pulse after power-on if MR1 and MR2 inputs are tied to GND. They do not supervise the actual voltage of the power supply like CAT825, which was not desired.